# HTTP status code for a blocked site?

Tags: networking, proxy

I am setting up a proxy server to filter "unwanted" traffic from the browser, e.g. requests made to google-analytics.com or facebook.com from shopping websites.

I would like for the proxy server to not forward these requests, and instead return an HTTP status code that would execute gracefully: i.e. not result in the browser giving an error to the user, and ideally not try over & over again.

My candidates so far are:

- 403 - Forbidden
- 503 - Service unavailable

Comment: FYI, according to wikipedia's list of HTTP status codes, 505 is "HTTP Version Not Supported". "Service Unavailable" is 503. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a perfect match for this scenario, however as a more general note I think it seems clear that this is a 400-series error rather than a 500-series error.

4xx are errors where the server for whatever reason considers the request invalid. (Ie, the client did something wrong)

5xx are errors where the server had no complaint about the request but is unable to process it. (Ie, the server is broken or otherwise incapable of processing valid requests)

In practice [403](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) may be the best option.

However, feel free to peruse the full [HTTP status code registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What happens if I make one up?  e.g. If I return 490, will the browser accept it as an "unknown 400-series error" or will it get confused?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Then no one knows what it means now and it may eventually clash with an actual properly defined 490 that means something completely different.

Comment: Of course.  But does the standard specify what the browser should do when a (currently) unknown response code like 490 is returned?